# How to change (add) a DIV class on every input change?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm asking if is possible to change (add) dinamically a class to a DIV on input change/validation. Less say for example I have two classes: success and error. The HTML markup is basically this one:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputFirstName">First Name: <span class="text-error">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="John">
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I fill the input with some value (no matter if is right or not because I handle validations trough PHP) then I should write `success` after `control-group` class or `error` when input was leave empty. How I do this using jQuery?

Comment: $("#yourId").addClass('className'), http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: To clarify, do you want to add the class `error` or `success` when the user *leaves* the *input field*, or when the user *submits* the *form*?

Comment: @QuinnStrahl when user leave field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this for every text field in the form (as requested):

```
$('#formId input[type=text]').blur(function(e) {
    var input = $(e.target);
    if (input.val().length > 0) {
        input.addClass('success');
        input.removeClass('error');
    }
    else {
        input.addClass('error');
        input.removeClass('success');
    }
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NwhvT/).

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
$div = $(".control-group");
if($("#inputFirstName").length){
  $div.addClass('success');
}else{
   $div.addClass('error');
}
```

Add it on form submit or any other appropriate event like `focusout` as given by [tymeJV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15910069/705773)

Comment: this should work for the #inputFirstName but what about for each field of type text in my form? It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `focusout` method

```
$("#inputFirstName").focusout(function() {
    var isValid; //Set to either true or false
    isValid ? $(".control-group").addClass("success") : $(".control-group").addClass("error");
});
```